# apache VirtualHost configuration - where to add them in redhat?

Tags: apache-2.2

On ubuntu, there are site-available structure already.

What about on redhat? Is it a good practice to keep the VirtualHost config under conf.d/ (where ssl.conf etc are), and add include directive in the httpd.conf? Or is it best to amend the httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1):

Put your virtual host configuration in:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/
```

While I'm not using VirtualHosts myself on RedHat I am using configuration files to point at different directories, e.g. I create a configuration file called `/etc/httpd/conf.d/monitor.conf`:

```
Alias /monitor /home/monitor/www

<Directory "/home/monitor/www">
    Options +Indexes

    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note that you do not need to explicitly link files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` as they are swept up by the following line in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
Include conf.d/*.conf
```